# SCrypt Lookup Gap Negative Effect

Tags: gpu, fpga, scrypt

I'm developing a Litecoin Miner for a processor that has only 32KB of internal memory. So I was looking at SCrypt algorithms and for Litecoin it uses N = 1024, that gives me 2^10 * 1 * 128 = 128KB memory use aproximate.

So I was looking into GPU Algorithms that has the parameter Lookup Gap. For reading I'm using kepler code from CudaMiner:
https://github.com/cbuchner1/CudaMiner/blob/master/kepler_kernel.cu (Line 535)

So I understand that lookup gap is a tradeoff between CPU and Memory. So higher is it, higher is my CPU use and lower my memory. What I didnt understand is how it works exactly.

In the code I have

```
int pos = c_N_1/LOOKUP_GAP, loop = 1 + (c_N_1-pos*LOOKUP_GAP);
```

That will make it look the scratchpad every LOOKUP_GAP byte (if its 2, it will be 0,2,4,6,8,10), but where is the more CPU Use of the algorithm?

My implementation will not be highly optimized, is something like *try to run*.

I also saw a FPGA Implementation that uses Interpolation ( https://github.com/kramble/FPGA-Litecoin-Miner ) this is more strange to me. I dunno how they could do interpolation of the values in scratchpad.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The increased CPU usage comes if you do not hit a pre-calculated entry. With LOOKUP 2 you are calculating 0-1023, but only storing 0, 2, 4, etc... So if you need the data for scratch-pad entry 3 you have to calculate it on the fly using the data from 2. This is an extra calculation vs. having them all stored permanently. As the lookup gap increases the amount of on the fly calculations you will do will increase.